# Update oldID for the records recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, cursor

I asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994720/update-oldid-field-based-on-fields-in-the-same-table) but I need more advance query now. The situation is, we have about 20,000 records of customers. Customers can renew and we just create a new record for it. There is no exact tracing back to which record was actually renewed. Now we have added the `old ID` field and I want to populate it with the exact old record. Now if it is renewed one time, that has been taken care of my old question and I can do it. The problem is if a record was renewed 3 or more time, I have to find the exact logic how the oldest record hopped to the newest one. For this we do not have a set rule but generally I am following `customer start date` (and the ID itself throws some light which record came first) and for now will use `customer start date` to populate all the records. I have included a test case here

```
create table #customer (
id int not null primary key identity,
cust_no varchar(12),
meter_no varchar(10),
startdate smalldatetime,
enddate smalldatetime,
oldid int null
)

insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-01-01', '2008-03-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-02-01', '2009-05-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-03-01', '2008-12-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-05-01', '2009-07-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-08-01', '2009-11-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-01-01', '2010-04-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-07-01', '2011-07-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null) 

-- I want this result in the last column

id   cust_no      meter_no   startdate      enddate        oldid           
---- ------------ ---------- -------------- -------------- -------         
1    AA111222     1111       2008-01-01     2008-03-01     base                      
2    AA111222     1111       2009-02-01     2009-05-01     3 
3    AA111222     1111       2008-03-01     2008-12-01     1            
4    AA111222     1111       2009-05-01     2009-07-01     2            
5    AA111222     1111       2009-08-01     2009-11-01     4            
6    AA111222     1111       2010-01-01     2010-04-01     5            
7    AA111222     1111       2010-07-01     2011-07-01     6            
8    AA111222     1111       2011-03-01     2011-07-01     7            
9    AA111222     1111       2011-07-01     2012-07-01     8
```

Note, different ways of doing it is appreciated so I can learn something too. So far I have looked at CTE, Join, Cursor but it would take some time for me to do it, if I can do it in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand wich result you exactly want. Do you want a query for the table, you pasted. Or a specific column?

Comment: oh forget about all the field. In the output that I posted, all columsn are original. The only column that I want changed/update is OLDID. The rest is just part of query. Does *not* need to be there.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I don't understand how `oldid` is being filled, what's the rule on it? Without a rule is impossible to assign anything. How did you do your example?

Comment: when a record is renewed, all its basic contents get copied over to a new record. So in the example code above, `cust_no` and `meter_no` carries over to new record (in actually table, a lot more records) but then customer `startdate` is different for the new record. So the new record oldid should match the ID of the record from where the contents were copied. I thought this was pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second Answer:
You can update the old_id column with the following statement!

```
 Update #customer
 SET oldid =
        (Select TOP 1 c_old.id from #customer c_old
          where c_old.enddate <= #customer.startdate
          and c_old.cust_no = #customer.cust_no
          and c_old.meter_no = #customer.meter_no
          and c_old.enddate = 
                           (
                             SELECT max(c.enddate) FROM #customer c
                               where c_old.cust_no = c.cust_no
                               and c_old.meter_no = c.meter_no
                               and #customer.startdate >= c.enddate
                            ) 
          )
  from #customer
 go
```

Comment: I made your above query run on the #customer table but it did not update the oldid at all

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at it on my server.

Comment: It now works. But my logic is different from yours. I don't know if I'm right. But a follower in my opinion must have a startdate after the enddate of the old value.

Comment: This is awesome. It almost works but record no 6 and 7 both have the same oldid which should be different. I will look into it.

Comment: That is, because the data is wrong, if I understand it right. My rule was: get the latest enddate where enddate is smaller or equal to the current startdate. For id 8, the oldid is also 6 because the enddate of 7 is later than the startdate of 8.

Comment: That's right my data is not that clean. But I will be able to work with this query using startdate only, that might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I know, that you probably don't like my answer, but I would change the design of the database and add 2 tables.
It would improve speed and reduce redundant data in your database.

```
Table 1
Contract
contract_id  |   startdate | meter_no  |   cust_no

Table 2
Contract_detail
contract_id  | startdate   | enddate
```

Here is how you could populate the tables with the old data:
I assume, that every Customer has just one contract, if he has more than one entry in the customer-table, then he renewed.

If you define the column contract_id in contract as autovalue, try the following.

```
This inserts for every cust_no and meter_no combination one entry.

Insert into contract
(cust_no, startdate, enddate, meter_no)
Select distinct cust_no
       ,Min (startdate)
       ,Max (enddate)
       ,meter_no
from customer
Group by cust_no, meter_no
GO

Insert into contract_detail
(contract_id, cust_no, startdate, enddate)
Select co.contract_id
       ,co.cust_no
       ,cu.startdate
       ,cu.enddate 
from contract co
inner join customer cu on co.cust_no = cu.cust_no 
           and co.meter_no = cu.meter_no
GO
```

Comment: No, anything is appreciated. But the real problem here is populate the contract_id for old records. How will I do it.

Answer (score 0):

The actual query that I used and that worked perfectly was. It was only possible after @chris answer. it is modified version of his.

```
 Update #customer
 SET oldid =
        (Select TOP 1 c_old.id from #customer c_old
          where c_old.startdate < #customer.startdate
          and c_old.cust_no = #customer.cust_no
          and c_old.meter_no = #customer.meter_no
          and c_old.id != #customer.id
          order by c_old.startdate desc
          )
  from #customer
```