# Update id recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

```
create table #customer (
id int not null primary key identity,
cust_no varchar(12),
meter_no varchar(10),
startdate smalldatetime,
enddate smalldatetime,
terminateDate smalldatetime,
oldid int null
)

insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-01-01', '2009-03-01','2008-04-15',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-01-01', '2009-05-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-03-01', '2008-12-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-05-01', '2009-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-08-01', '2009-11-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-01-01', '2010-04-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-07-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('BB111222','1112','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('BB111222','1112','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-09-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 

select * from #customer
```

**Scenario:** We have over 10,000 rows. Some customer renew, other don't. We want to build hierarchy

Problem: Update the `oldID` column of all columns based on the fact that `cust_no` and `meter_no` together give a unique combination that identifies a particular customer.

Main help is need in rows 1,2,3 both have same `cust_no, meter_no` and `start_date` that means they belong to the same customer. Since the `startdate` is the same, we have to look at `terminateDate`, if two rows have the same start data and one of them is terminated, the terminated row comes first in hierarchy and the other one comes later.

Here

- row #3 `oldid` should be 1
- row #1 `oldid` should be 2
- row #2 `oldid` should be null
- The rest is pretty much in chronological order.

I tried this query which did work for my old question question [Update oldID for the records recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132026/update-oldid-for-the-records-recursively) but I am stuck here. Spend quite a bit of time on this one.

```
 Update #customer
 SET oldid =
        (Select TOP 1 c_old.id from #customer c_old
          where c_old.startdate <= #customer.startdate
          and c_old.cust_no = #customer.cust_no
          and c_old.meter_no = #customer.meter_no
          and c_old.id != #customer.id
          and #customer.oldid is null
          order by c_old.startdate desc,c_old.terminateDate desc
          )
  from #customer
```

I simply reproduced data this close to the model.

Comment: A faster and clearer query is preferred. Mine takes 4+ minutes to execute on all records.

Comment: Rows 1-3 do not have the same start date. Rows 1 & 2 have a start date of `01-01-08` while row #3 has a start date of `03-01-08`???

Comment: So `enddate` does not play a role here? Probably better just to leave it out of the example.

Comment: yes enddate does not play a role but can be used in certain capacity maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think recursion is necessary since each ID is only reverting to the previous one record, not to the oldest ID.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_no, Meter_No ORDER BY StartDate, TerminateDate) [RowNum]
    FROM    #Customer
)
UPDATE  #Customer
SET     OldID = cte.OldID
FROM    #Customer c
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  a.ID, b.ID [OldID]
            FROM    CTE a
                    LEFT JOIN CTE b
                        ON b.Meter_No = a.Meter_No
                        AND a.Cust_No = b.Cust_no
                        AND a.RowNum = b.RowNum + 1
        ) cte
            ON cte.ID = c.ID
```

The CTE is not really necessary, subqueries would work equally well, but I tend to use CTE when I would use the same subquery twice or more.

Comment: Because records 9, 11, and 12 are the newest records for each customer, therefore they can't be old IDs (As I understand the question)

Comment: You could very well be right, I am still lost as to the requirements.

Comment: You are right. Recursion is not needed in this case. I guess I simplified, then over complicated it myself

Comment: Just checked and this yields the same results as the answer posted by @JustinPihony which the comments lead me to believe is not what the OP wants, so all I have done is simplify a wrong answer, which is not very helpful to anyone...

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what is wrong as I had chatted with crocodile and my results matched what he wanted exactly. I will be curious to know the issue

Comment: Amazing query, blazing fast, does everything!

Answer (score 2):

Below is the entire query (including the base code from above). Per my chat with crocodile, the results match exactly as requested. This solution is without the previous recursion as garreth pointed out that it is unnecessary. I did keep the recursive solution below in case the problem becomes more complicated and needs actual recursion. Both solutions should work, though

```
create table #customer (
    id int not null primary key identity,
    cust_no varchar(12),
    meter_no varchar(10),
    startdate smalldatetime,
    enddate smalldatetime,
    terminateDate smalldatetime,
    oldid int null
)

insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-01-01', '2009-03-01','2008-04-15',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-01-01', '2009-05-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-03-01', '2008-12-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-05-01', '2009-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-08-01', '2009-11-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-01-01', '2010-04-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-07-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('BB111222','1112','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('BB111222','1112','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-09-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 

; WITH RankingCTE (id, cust_no, meter_no, startdate, enddate, terminatedate, 
        oldid, CustomerRank)
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY cust_no, meter_no ORDER BY startdate, terminatedate) 
                    AS CustomerRank
    FROM #customer
)
UPDATE #customer
SET oldid = OrganizedCTE.OldID
FROM #customer
    JOIN
        (   SELECT  BaseCTE.ID, NextInRankCTE.ID AS OldID
            FROM    RankingCTE AS BaseCTE
                    LEFT JOIN RankingCTE AS NextInRankCTE
                        ON NextInRankCTE.Meter_No = BaseCTE.Meter_No
                            AND NextInRankCTE.Cust_No = BaseCTE.Cust_no
                            AND BaseCTE.CustomerRank = NextInRankCTE.CustomerRank + 1
        ) AS OrganizedCTE
            ON OrganizedCTE.ID = #customer.ID
;

SELECT * FROM #customer
```

This is the recursive solution, with the full solution also:

```
create table #customer (
    id int not null primary key identity,
    cust_no varchar(12),
    meter_no varchar(10),
    startdate smalldatetime,
    enddate smalldatetime,
    terminateDate smalldatetime,
    oldid int null
)

insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-01-01', '2009-03-01','2008-04-15',null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-01-01', '2009-05-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2008-03-01', '2008-12-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-05-01', '2009-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2009-08-01', '2009-11-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-01-01', '2010-04-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2010-07-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('AA111222','1111','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('BB111222','1112','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('BB111222','1112','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-09-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-03-01', '2011-07-01',null,null) 
insert into #customer values('CC111222','1113','2011-07-01', '2012-07-01',null,null) 

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY cust_no, meter_no ORDER BY startdate ASC, terminatedate ASC) 
                AS CustomerRank
INTO #RankingTable
FROM #customer

;WITH SortingCTE(id, cust_no, meter_no, startdate, enddate, terminatedate, 
        oldid, CustomerRank)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT id, cust_no, meter_no, startdate, enddate, terminatedate, 
                null as oldid, CustomerRank
    FROM #RankingTable
    WHERE CustomerRank = 1
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT #RankingTable.id, #RankingTable.cust_no, #RankingTable.meter_no,
                #RankingTable.startdate, #RankingTable.enddate,
                #RankingTable.terminatedate, SortingCTE.id as oldid, 
                #RankingTable.CustomerRank
    FROM #RankingTable 
        JOIN SortingCTE 
            ON SortingCTE.cust_no = #RankingTable.cust_no
                AND SortingCTE.meter_no = #RankingTable.meter_no
                AND SortingCTE.CustomerRank+1 = #RankingTable.CustomerRank  
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
UPDATE #customer
SET oldid = SortingCTE.oldid
FROM SortingCTE
    JOIN #customer on #customer.id = SortingCTE.id
;

SELECT * FROM #customer
```

Comment: Worked on that before, with no luck :)

Comment: The only thing I am curious about, is why does row#2 have a null id, wouldnt that be 3?

Comment: #row2 is the oldest record (base record) so it should have null oldid.

Comment: Actually, I did not look at that right at first. The first 9 rows are the same, so what IDs would those be? It might be beneficial if you could fill in the id that you expect for the entire example set? Just to clarify your rules?

Comment: ok sorry the ID that we use is very first ID which in this case is automatically generated. this is for internal use but to identify a customer we use cust_no and meter_no.

Comment: OK, I think that the data you posted is wrong, first off? The third row has a different start date, yet you are explaining as if it is the same start date? I am still not quite sure how your logic is working based on your example, though? I do not understand why you are saying the order is what it is? Can you double check your data as you posted it, and then give us what the example data would look like after being transformed? This will help understand your logic rules easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8275/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-the-crocodile-hunter)

Comment: @JustinPihony You expressed concern over my solution getting messy, but this is arguably more complicated and longer than mine.

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? I ran this myself and verified it to your example code...

Comment: Kevev22 so you are saying an expressive partition and cte are more complicated than a series of ors and cases?

Comment: @JustinPihony Not necessarily, but I would say it's debatable. (Also there are no case statements in my answer). Though it looks like both of our answers are still incorrect.

Comment: OK, I have updated the code so that it has the entire solution. You should be able to cut and paste and get the appropriate results. I have two solutions just so you can see the difference of one with recursion and one without. However, garethd was correct in pointing out that recursion is not necessary here. Again, I have verified this against the results discussed in chat. If this does not work, please provide the reason, as it matches 100% for me

Comment: This worked perfectly on test data but give an error on my actual table ''RankingCTE' has more columns than were specified in the column list'.

Comment: WITH RankingCTE (id, cust_no, meter_no, startdate, enddate, terminatedate, oldid, CustomerRank)....All of these columns, except for CustomerRank must be in your temp table #customer since a select * is being done. Think of a CTE as a kind of temp table.

Answer (score 2):

I think [@GarethD's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473400/297408) can be simplified like this:

```
;
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Cust_no, Meter_No
      ORDER BY StartDate, TerminateDate
    )
  FROM #Customer
)
UPDATE CTE
SET OldID = (
  SELECT ID
  FROM CTE a
  WHERE CTE.Cust_no  = a.Cust_no
    AND CTE.Meter_no = a.Meter_no
    AND CTE.RowNum   = a.RowNum + 1
)
```

Comment: This was my first thought, then when I tested I got unexpected results, I have just tried it again at home and got the results I expected... Weird, I must have written it wrong earlier. I agree this is simplified, and more efficient. It is also compliant with SQL standards, and does use SQL server's `UPDATE ... FROM ... JOIN` anomoly.

Comment: @GarethD solution worked totally fine. But I had one problem, if terminate date was not supplied, in that case it picked the wrong oldid. There is a way to use ISNULL() and make all those records with null to appear on top rather than bottom because they are active records in my case. Looking into that now. I though about another logic today, to create a temp table, sort the data first and then using the data in allready sorted table to update the oldid field